# How can I check the checkbox state using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

How can I verify if a checkbox is checked or unchecked using Selenium?

Because method "**element.Selected**" does not work in this case.

Here is the HTML code if a checkbox is checked:

```
<td class="dxgvCommandColumn_MetropolisBlue dxgv" onclick="aspxGVScheduleCommand('messageGrid',['Select',1],1)" align="center">
    <span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked_MetropolisBlue">
        <input id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1" value="U" readonly="readonly" style="border-width:0;width:0;height:0;padding:0;margin:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;" type="text"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

Here is the HTML code if a checkbox is unchecked:

```
<td class="dxgvCommandColumn_MetropolisBlue dxgv" onclick="aspxGVScheduleCommand('messageGrid',['Select',1],1)" align="center">
    <span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked_MetropolisBlue dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys">
        <input id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1" value="U" readonly="readonly" style="border-width:0;width:0;height:0;padding:0;margin:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;" type="text"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

Image:

[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: SPAN has different classes between and checked and unchecked. You can check if the span has specific class name to see if it is checked.

Comment: have you tried **element.checked** ?

Comment: I see a [readonly](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-readonly-attribute) tag on your input, are you sure the value of the checkbox is actually changed and the difference is not purely styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared, it's clear that the `<span>` tag of the *outerHTML* of the *Checkbox* contains the following *class* attributes:

- Checked

  ```
   <span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked_MetropolisBlue">
       <input id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1" value="U" readonly="readonly" style="border-width:0;width:0;height:0;padding:0;margin:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;" type="text"/>
   </span>
  ```
- Unchecked

  ```
   <span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked_MetropolisBlue dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys">
       <input id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1" value="U" readonly="readonly" style="border-width:0;width:0;height:0;padding:0;margin:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;" type="text"/>
   </span>
  ```

So to check if the *Check Box* is **checked** or **unchecked** you can induce the following validation:

```
if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='messageGrid_DXSelBtn1']//preceding::span[1]")).GetAttribute("class").contains("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked_MetropolisBlue"))
    Console.WriteLine("Check Box is Checked");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Check Box is Unchecked");
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works well.
Thanks to all of you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

"element.Selected" is not working, because you do not have checkbox element on the page at all. Selenium does not know that the input "looks" like checkbox. It is just HTML input of type: "text".

Your only chance is to get the JavaScript executor and check the attributes yourself (elm is your Selenium "input" object got by XPath or CSS selector):

#### To set the value

```
ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);",
              new object[] {elm, "value", value });
```

### To get the value:

```
ExecuteScriptReturn("return arguments[0].getAttribute(arguments[1]);",
                    new object[] {elm, "value" });
```

where the method is:

```
private void ExecuteScript(string script, object[] arguments)
{
    var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_browser;
    jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(script, arguments);
}

private void ExecuteScriptReturn(string script, object[] arguments)
{
    var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_browser;
    return (string)jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(script, arguments);
}
```

EDIT:

Just note you in fact are not checking the value of input in this case, but the value of class of these two elements:

```
span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys dxWeb_edtCheckBox**Checked**_MetropolisBlue"
```

and

```
span id="messageGrid_DXSelBtn1_D" class="dxWeb_edtCheckBox**Unchecked**_MetropolisBlue dxICheckBox_MetropolisBlue dxichSys"
```